# Displays incorrect values after created Date Dimension table in Power BI

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dax

My Fact table "Premiums" has Premium value and DateTime column (EffectiveDate). 
If I look at the Premium by MONTH(EffectiveDate) - it looks correct. Sorry, its not sorted.

[image]

But then if I create table Dates, join it to Premiums table on EffectiveDate column and try to look at Premiums by Month - it looks completely different.

[image]

[image]

I tried two different ways to create Calendar table. Still the same incorrect values.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to match a datetime (`Premiums[EffectiveDate]`) to a date (`Dates[Date]`), so it's not matching most of your rows.

Try adding a calculated column to your `Premiums` table that converts `EffectiveDate` to a date type and then match that up with your calendar table. The following are a few ways that should work for your calculated column:

```
Calculated Column = Premiums[EffectiveDate].[Date]
Calculated Column = EDATE(Premiums[EffectiveDate],0)
Calculated Column = ROUNDDOWN(Premiums[EffectiveDate],0)
Calculated Column = DATE(YEAR(Premiums[EffectiveDate]),MONTH(Premiums[EffectiveDate]),DAY(Premiums[EffectiveDate]))
Calculated Column = DATEVALUE(FORMAT(Premiums[EffectiveDate],"yyyy/mm/dd"))
```

---

**Edit**: If you don't need the time part of the `EffectiveDate` column for anything, then just convert both that column and the calendar date column to date types, and it should match up.

Comment: Both columns were datetime format. Effective date has an actual time, but Date column has 00:00:000 time. 
So I changed EffectiveDate to Date type and it works correct now. I did not know it can be a problem.
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Oleg Right. It's because it was trying to match the time portion as well, but the calendar had everything at midnight.

Comment: Oh! Got it. Interesting. Thanks again ))